# Activate window in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I wrote the application to Outlook in VBA and now I want to write it again in VB.net (to make it independent application). 
I have specific problem I couldn't find answer for - to navigate in outlook explorer I wrote procedure, which activates explorer, sends key down and activates form again. When I start application in Visual Studio this procedure works perfectly, but when I close VS and run single exe, Outlook explorer doesn't activate - it's only blinking on taskbar, then sendkey doesn't work and next email is not selected. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim app As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application")
        Dim oApp As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(app)

        oApp.ActiveExplorer.Activate()

        SendKeys.Send("{Down}")

        Me.Activate()

    End Sub
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried to give it some time, i.e. Thread.Sleep for some amount after the `Activate`?

Answer (score 1):

I did it with code below ;)

```
    Dim p As Process
    Dim window_name As String

    For Each p In Process.GetProcessesByName("outlook")
        window_name = p.MainWindowTitle.ToString
    Next

    AppActivate(window_name)

    Thread.Sleep(100)

    SendKeys.Send("{Up}")

    Me.Activate()
```

Thanks for clues ;)

Answer (score 0):

Within Visual Studio, try "Start without Debugging" in the Debug menu. This should be equivalent to running the executable, but you can then attach the debugger ("Attach to Process" in the debug menu) after it starts and see if that leads to a clue.....

Comment: No, It works still without problems. I noticed that when VS in running and I start single exe application, it also works perfectly. Problem is only when VS is not running

Comment: Have you tried to give it some time, i.e. `Thread.Sleep` for some amount?

Comment: I tried today, but it also didn't work. I noticed, that operation (also without thread.sleep) works when I minimize Outlook at the beginning of code. Then Outlook explorer is activated. If this windows is not minimized, application assumes that it is active so it doesn't have to be activated again.